# SSIS Excel C# Import Script returns empty table when importing xlsx file saved by other users

Tags: c#, excel, ssis, oledb, xlsx

I have created a SSIS import task, where in For Each Loop container I have Data Flow Task, in which I have Script Component where I try to import `xlsx` files from external drive folder to upload to database.

My excel connection method is:

```
private DataTable QueryData(string FileName, string Header, string QueryString)
{
        string connectionString;
        OleDbConnection excelConnection;
        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter;
        DataSet excelDataSet;

        connectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0; Data Source ="
                + FileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 XML;HDR= "
                + Header + ";IMEX=1;\"";
        excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(QueryString, excelConnection);
        excelDataSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(excelDataSet, "Sheet1");
        excelConnection.Close();
        return excelDataSet.Tables["Sheet1"];
}
```

The Script component works fine with files saved by me.

When the component tries to get information from Excel files that are saved by others, the method returns only one row with empty `object[]`.

I have tried unsuccessfully to Run the SSIS as Administrator and also in the server as I suspect there might be problems with file permissions.

Comment: Are your files saved to the same path as the other users?  Is the path you are pulling for files the same format they are using?  i.e. you are not using a mapped drive/local folder path like D:\  but a network path like \\network\etc  ?  Are both paths to the directly the same for your files and theirs? with just the file names different?

Comment: Yes, files are the same, one saved by me (Excel "save as"), other saved by different user (original file), in the same folder. The path is network path. Also, I tried first to copy the folder to my C:\ drive (local drive) and ran the script there, but the result was the same.